# SharePoint Farm Feature

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-feature

I want to install .wsp  but it gives an error saying that there is a farm feature in which need to be removed. how to Remove Farm Feature (Farm Level Feature) from Central Admin or trough Power-Shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because there is already a solution with the same name (i.e. it is already installed)

From PowerShell with the SharePoint snapin loaded, first run:

```
Get-SPSolution
```

This will list all the installed solutions. Look for the solution that has a matching name and verify that it is listed.

If you want to remove the existing solution, run the following:

```
Remove-SPSolution -Identity the_solution.wsp
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was though i remove the SPSolution some farm level features remain there. in my case the BDC model i created for my external content type. how i get it sorted was i add SPSolution and installed it with -Force and then uninstalled it and removed the solution. other than that there is no specific was to remove only the farm feature as i found. i had to remove the whole solution.